# Connection refused when using curl?

Tags: java, spring-boot, curl

I am on a mac and am building a java spring boot project by following this tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

However when I try to access the api through this command:

`curl localhost:8080/api`

I get the following message

```
Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure what the problem is!  Grateful for your help,
Many thanks,

Comment: `Connection refused` means that your server is not running, or is bound to a different interface than loopback (localhost).

Comment: @ernest_k this is happening to me it works if you type directly on the browser but not with curl or some proxy (chimurai/http-proxy-middleware in my case)